# In a Spring Boot project, the Elasticsearch index cannot be created using Spring Data Commons during startup

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using the Spring Boot framework to build a project. This piece of code has already passed testing in the development environment.

My JDK version is 1.8, Spring Boot version is 2.6.3, Spring Data Commons version is 2.3.2.RELEASE, and Elasticsearch version is 7.4.

My approach is as follows:

1. Creating an Elasticsearch mapping template.

```
PUT _template/excluded-time-record-template
{
    "template":"excluded-time-record*",
    "mappings": {
        "properties" : {
        "_class" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "createTime" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "dimension" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "excludedEndTime" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "excludedStartTime" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "isLeaf" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "path" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "pathLabel" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "repeatPeriod" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "sellerId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

2. Automatically creating this index using Spring Data.The DTO data structure looks like this:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Document(indexName = " excluded-time-record" + DYNAMIC_INDEX_SUFFIX)
public class ExcludedTimeRecordDTO {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Byte)
    private Integer dimension;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String rangeId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String rangeName;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String reason;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Byte)
    private Integer repeatPeriod;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long repeatStartTime;

   
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long repeatEndTime;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long excludedStartTime;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long excludedEndTime;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String cascadeInfo;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long createTime;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long sellerId;

    private CascadeNode node;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<String> path;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<String> pathLabel;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
    private Boolean isLeaf;

}
```

I have deployed this code in three out of four production environments without any errors. However, when deploying the code in the last environment, the Spring Boot project fails to start.

The error message is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'excludedTimeRecordRepository' defined in com.service.repository.ExcludedTimeRecordRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is RestStatusException{status=400} org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]];
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(Default
SingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeanByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:520)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:673)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:329)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is RestStatusException{status=400} org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]];
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:543)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: RestStatusException{status=400} org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]];
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:69)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:427)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:410)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.doCreate(RestIndexTemplate.java:83)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractIndexTemplate.createWithMapping(AbstractIndexTemplate.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]];
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:176)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2011)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1988)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1745)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1717)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1684)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create$original$so0vxYbT(IndicesClient.java:134)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create$original$so0vxYbT$accessor$EhbBKuxs(IndicesClient.java)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient$auxiliary$qpXIPEQB.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.agent.core.plugin.interceptor.enhance.InstMethodsInter.intercept(InstMethodsInter.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create(IndicesClient.java)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doCreate$0(RestIndexTemplate.java:83)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:408)
        ... 75 more
        Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://internal-xxx.com], URI [/excluded-time-record-2023-08?master_timeout=30s&timeout=30s], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]"}},"status":400}
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:326)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:296)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:270)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2082)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
                ... 84 more
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [pathLabel] has unsupported parameters:  [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]]
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:485)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:396)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:426)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.failureFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:592)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:168)
        ... 87 more
```

Why did this problem occur? I know that in version 7.X, specifying 'Document' is not required when creating mappings. Any advice would be very helpful to me. Thank you.

What aspects should I consider regarding this issue? Could it be a version conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your code:

A. You have a leading whitespace in the index name which means your template will never match

```
  @Document(indexName = " excluded-time-record" + DYNAMIC_INDEX_SUFFIX)
                        ^^^
```

B. This is the real cause of the error: You declare `pathLabel` as nested in your DTO but as normal text field in your mapping. Same issue for `path`. You either need to declare both fields as `@Field(type = FieldType.Text)` or make sure your mapping has a `nested` field declared to contain `path` and `pathLabel`

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough response. You must have read my question very carefully. I have resolved my issue – my project has successfully started in a Kubernetes container. However, I haven't yet identified the specific cause of the problem I mentioned earlier. Thank you again for your attentive response.

Comment: If you haven't fixed the first issue, the index probably got created without matching your template and the `path` and `pathLabel` fields have been created as nested fields as specified in your DTO. Check your index list and make sure you haven't created an index with an initial whitespace

Comment: I will follow your advice diligently. Thank you.